# How can I show a symbol like this in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

[image]

How can I show the last character? ie.  "i" in a circle.

One way is to put image, but is there an alternate way like "Unicode" in XML or TextView with background circle or some other way?

Comment: "\u24D8" may help. But Android should be able to interpret this

Comment: above is working on emulator."\u24D8". Can give example code if required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In unicode, it's [CIRCLED LATIN SMALL LETTER I](http://unicode-table.com/en/24D8/) ⓘ, XML `&#9432;`.

Comment: took its corresponding unicode number "U+24D8" and set the text in TextView as "\u24D8". It worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set following as background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="1"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="oval"
    android:thicknessRatio="2" >

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#777" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this thread for char table

http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

http://oreilly.com/actionscript/excerpts/actionscript-for-flash/appendix-b.html

we can create custom drawable resource . pls read this thread.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape